# App crashes while showing NearByPlaces in recyclerview without displaying in MapView in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-recyclerview

[Here I have setLayoutManager to be Linear Layout to the Recyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQIPP.png)[here we can](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6IgY.png) I am trying to create to show Near By Places in recyclerView in a child Fragment which uses  info(Named As hello ) is the place name that it display
  Viewpager (Parent Fragment is also a fragment of ParentViewPager).My App Got Crashes and Do not 
 pass List of items to be display in recyclerView. Here is ChildFragmentClass Code:

```
    public class NearByFragment extends Fragment implements
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
            LocationListener {
        RecyclerView mRecycler;
        //    private GoogleMap mMap;
        private GoogleApiClient client;
        private LocationRequest locationRequest;
        //    private Marker currentLocationmMarker;
        public static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE = 99;
        int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 8000;
        double latitude, longitude;

        NearByFragment byFragment;
        private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
        private PlacesClient placesClient;
        private List<AutocompletePrediction> predictionList;
        private Location mLastKnownLocation;
        private LocationCallback locationCallback;
        private final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15;
        GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData;
        Object dataTransfer[];
        LocationManager locationManager;

        NearByModelClass nearByModelClass;
        List<NearByModelClass>list=new ArrayList<>();
        View view;
        public NearByFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_near_by, container, false);
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment

            byFragment=this;



            mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());
            Places.initialize(getContext(), getString(R.string.google_maps_api));
            placesClient = Places.createClient(getContext());        
            dataTransfer = new Object[2];
            getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
            String resturant = "restuarant";
            String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, resturant);
            Log.i("url",url);
    //        dataTransfer[0] = mMap;
            dataTransfer[1] = url;
            getNearbyPlacesData.execute(dataTransfer);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Showing Nearby Restaurants", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return view;
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode == 51) {
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    getting device location. 
                    getDeviceLocation();
                }
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        private void getDeviceLocation(){
            mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                                if(mLastKnownLocation != null){
                                   // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                                } else {
                                    final LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                                    locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
                                    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
                                    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                                    locationCallback = new LocationCallback(){
                                        @Override
                                        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                                            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                                            if(locationResult == null) {
                                                return;
                                            }
                                            mLastKnownLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                                            //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                                            mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                                        }
                                    };
                                    mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);

                                }
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "unable to get last location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            locationRequest.setInterval(100);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, locationRequest, this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            mLastKnownLocation = location;
            Log.d("lat = ",""+latitude);
        }
        private String getUrl(double latitude , double longitude , String nearbyPlace)
        {

            StringBuilder googlePlaceUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
            googlePlaceUrl.append("location="+latitude+","+longitude);
            googlePlaceUrl.append("&radius="+PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
            googlePlaceUrl.append("&type="+nearbyPlace);
            googlePlaceUrl.append("&sensor=true");
            googlePlaceUrl.append("&key="+"APIs");

            Log.d("MapsActivity", "url = "+googlePlaceUrl.toString());

            return googlePlaceUrl.toString();
        }
        public void preppareList(List<NearByModelClass>list ) {
            mRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.nearby_recycler);
            mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
           NearByRecyclerAdapterClass recyclerAdapterClass = new NearByRecyclerAdapterClass(list);
           mRecycler.setAdapter(recyclerAdapterClass);

        }
    Here is my Code of NearPlaces.java class extended by AsynTask I have called function Name PreapparedList of that child fragment to pass list:

    class GetNearbyPlacesData extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {

        private String googlePlacesData;
        private GoogleMap mMap;
        String url;

        NearByModelClass nearByModelClass;
        List<NearByModelClass>list=new ArrayList<>();
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... objects){
            mMap = (GoogleMap)objects[0];
            url = (String)objects[1];

            DownloadURL downloadURL = new DownloadURL();
            try {
                googlePlacesData = downloadURL.readUrl(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return googlePlacesData;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s){

            List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlaceList;
            DataParser parser = new DataParser();
            nearbyPlaceList = parser.parse(s);
            Log.d("nearbyplacesdata","called parse method");
            showNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlaceList);
        }

        private void showNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlaceList)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < nearbyPlaceList.size(); i++)
            {
                HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = nearbyPlaceList.get(i);

                String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
                String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");
                double lat = Double.parseDouble( googlePlace.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble( googlePlace.get("lng"));
                Log.i("hello",placeName);
```

this is where i want to post my list of data to That Fragment by calling it's method  m.preppareList

```
                NearByFragment m =new NearByFragment();
                nearByModelClass=new NearByModelClass(placeName,vicinity,lat,lng);
                list.add(nearByModelClass);
                m.preppareList(list);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the complete [stack trace from the crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Vladydlav Matviienko it doesn't answer my Question.

Comment: Mike M I have edited my Question by attaching pictures of the Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

After Hardship, I came across that I don't need to make GetNearbyPlacesData class as separate class but it should be a nested class inside that fragment.